# transparency texture not showing other object?

Tags: texturing, transparency

So I have a video and I have the checker texture, and have set it up so that its black and white, and then I put the color into alpha of the output node, so that I have this white and transparent dotted line. BUT, the "transparent" part of the line goes THROUGH an object right behind it.
[image]
I'm using blender internal.
help?

Comment: Make sure you are not using mask transparency. Try Z transparency instead

Comment: Yep, it sure is, solved my question